# How do I get subset of a Java XML org.w3c.dom.Document?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have a XML org.w3c.dom.Document object.

It looks sorta like this:

```
<A>
  <B>
     <C/>
     <D/>
     <E/>
     <F/>
   </B>
   <G>
     <H/>
     <H/>
     <J/>
   </G>
 </A>
```

How can I convert the Document object so that it strips off the root node  and returns another Document object subset (selected by name) that looks like this:

```
<G>
   <H/>
   <H/>
   <J/>
</G>
```

I am hoping for something like this:

```
...
Document doc = db.parse(file);
Document subdoc = doc.getDocumentSubsetByName("G"); //imaginary method name
NodeList nodeList = subdoc.getElementsByTagName("H");
```

But I am having trouble finding such a thing.

---

The answer turns out to be something like this:

```
...
Document doc = db.parse();
doc.getDocumentElement.normalize();
NodeList a = doc.getElementsByTagName("A");
Element AsubNode = null;
if (a.item(0) != null) {
   AsubNode = (Element) a.item(0);
   nodeList = AsubNode.getElementsByTagName("G");
...
```

Comment: I'm getting the feeling the solution has something to do with casting the G node to a Element object and then getting a nodeList from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `getElementsByTagName("G")` to get the `G` elements, then pick one of them and call `getElementsByTagName("H")` on that.

Comment: that first method gets me a NodeList object but I want to "end up" with a NodeList. therefore, I need to subset the document "before" I convert to a NodeList.  that is the dilemma.

Comment: I don't quite understand the difficulty with that. From a NodeList, you can get a specific Node, which you can then cast to an Element (if necessary, depending on your language) and then call getElementsByTagName on the Element.

Comment: Oh I see you're using Java. So yes, you'll have to cast.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you could always use XPath to do the same thing:

```
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

final XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
final NodeList list = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/A/G/H", 
    doc.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

This begins to pay off when the path to your elements begins to become more complex (requiring attribute predicates, etc..)